# Excel VBA: Loop through range and delete columns with all 0 values

Tags: excel

I've just started learning VBA and I've been stuck on a problem for a while and hope someone can help.

What I want to do is to first loop through each row in a dynamic range that I copied from another sheet starting at column 8 out of 58 columns and check if the value in each cell in the row is either "0" or another value.

If the value is "0", then I want it to go to the next row and check to see if that value is also zero. Continue this until the very last row if all cell values are 0 or go to the next column if there is a cell value other than 0.

If all the cells in the column are 0, I want to delete the column before going to the next column. Repeat this process for all the columns in the range.

The end result would be that all the columns in the initial range with only 0 values will be deleted while columns with values will remain.

Can someone please help?

Below is the code I have so far:

```
Dim CopyRange as Range 
Dim iRow as Range

Set CopyRange = Range("H2", Range("H2").End(xldown))

For each iRow in CopyRange

if iRow = "0" then
activecell.offset(1,0).select
else

end if 

next iRow
```

*delete column
*go to next column and repeat for remaining columns

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code,

```
Sub searchForZero()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
For i = 58 To 8 Step -1
    j = Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(j, i)), 0) = j - 1 Then
        Columns(i).Delete
    End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

This code loops from column 58 to 8 and deletes the column which has all 0's in it.

Note:- This works only if your data start at row 1. If not you have to modify the 'j' variable accordingly

Comment: thanks. how would I modify the j variable? I have a header tab on the first row that I want to ignore.

Comment: @CharlieChen I have modified the code. Try it out